# nanopb pb_istream_from_buffer - what is value of bufsize?

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c, nanopb

```
pb_istream_t pb_istream_from_buffer(const pb_byte_t *buf, size_t bufsize);
```

> buf -     Pointer to byte array to read from.
> bufsize   Size of the byte array.

What is the argument for `bufsize`? Is it the macro in the `.pb.h` file under the heading `/* Maximum encoded size of messages (where known) */`?

The example in [simple.c](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/blob/master/examples/simple/simple.c) is slightly confusing because it uses the buffer that it created for the output example.

My payload can be up to **2048** and the encoded maximum is **2051**; which one do I pass in as `size_t bufsize`?

Answer (score 0):

It is the actual length of the message to be decoded. Protobuf messages do not have any terminator themselves, so the length of the message data must be passed to the decoder.

Comment: But if it's variable, which mine is, then the actual length is unknowable. So it has to be either the payload size or the maximum encoded size; which is it?

Comment: You need to pass the length to the receiver in some way. That depends on how you transport the messages, see e.g. https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/docs/concepts.html#message-framing .You do know the length on the encoder side, it is available as `ostream.bytes_written`.

Comment: This is for incoming data. If someone is passing me a stream, I don't know how many bytes they actually wrote.

Comment: To decode a protobuf message, you need to know the length. The format is designed that way, and it applies to all protobuf libraries.

Comment: The maximum length or actual encoded length? My current interface only specifies the incoming buffer; should it also have included a separate length field?